# Perché si chiamano "baroni"?

Tags: word-usage, etymology

I baroni in contesto universitario:

> - Per baroni si intendono quei professori di ruolo che al contempo coprono 
>     all'interno della stessa università per cui lavorano, un qualche incarico di responsabilità (per esempio Rettore, Direttore di un Dipartimento, Preside di facoltà, Preside di Corso di Laurea e via dicendo). 
>     Più è importante il posto di responsabilità e quindi il potere che i baroni hanno, più hanno possibilità di influenzare le scelte dell'Università stessa.

Comment: Non so da dove venga questa citazione (cerchiamo di indicare le fonti), ma non sono sicuro che spieghi bene il senso di “barone”. In molti dipartimenti e facoltà, direttori, presidi e altri incarichi di responsabilità sono una seccatura che tocca via via ai docenti con maggiore anzianità, i quali sono poi ben lieti di liberarsene. Quindi non è specificamente il fatto di ricoprire quegli incarichi, ma di detenere una certa forma di potere, formalizzato o no che sia.

Comment: @DaG - grazie per la precisazione, ma la mia come la tua sono definizioni che purtroppo non hanno conferme 'ufficiali'. Io perlomeno non ne ho trovate. Detto questo, la domanda è: perché li chiamano "baroni"?

Comment: Non lo scrivo come risposta perché non ho un riferimento per supportarlo, ma immagino che l'origine sia perché abusano del loro potere comportandosi come dei prepotenti signorotti locali, alla don Rodrigo nei Promessi Sposi per intenderci. E confermo quanto scrive DaG: nell'uso comune il termine è legato al comportamento arrogante e all'abuso di potere, non agli incarichi ricoperti.

Comment: Fino alla definizione, ne possiamo trovare una “ufficiale”: il Treccani, sotto “[barone](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/barone1/)” dà tra l'altro «i docenti universitarî che sfruttano abilmente il loro prestigio e le loro relazioni per esercitare un vero e proprio potere politico sia all’interno del mondo universitario sia fuori di esso». Quanto al perché, a parte il generico riferimento a uno dei massimi titoli del mondo feudale, spero che ci sia chi sa qualcosa di specifico.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni - si penso che il senso sia quello. Perché baroni e non marchesi, duchi o altro non è chiaro.